# Django - reload div upon form submit

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to refresh a certain div in a django application when a form is submitted.

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="notesColumn">
  {% crispy note_form %}
  {% include 'item/item_notes.html' %}
</div>
```

item_notes.html

```
<div class="panel-group panel-group-simple m-b-0" id="notesList" aria-multiselectable="true" role="tablist">
    {% for note in object.itemnote_set.all reversed %}
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="noteHeading{{ forloop.counter }}" role="tab">
                <a class="panel-title collapsed" data-parent="#notesList"
                   data-toggle="collapse" href="#noteCollapse{{ forloop.counter }}"
                   aria-controls="noteCollapse{{ forloop.counter }}" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="tag tag-default">{{ note.owner.first_name }}</span>
                    {{ note.get_action_display|upper }}
                    <small class="panel-actions">{{ note.date_added }}</small>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="noteCollapse{{ forloop.counter }}"
                 aria-labelledby="noteHeading{{ forloop.counter }}" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false"
                 style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ note.content }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

app.js (included in index.html)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#notesTab form").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

  $('#notesList').remove();

  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url item_notes %}",
    success: function(data){
      $('#notesColumn').html('data');
    }
  })
})
```

views.py

```
def item_notes(request):
  return render_to_response(request, 'candidate/candidate_notes.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'item/profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemProfile.as_view(), name='item_profile'),
  url(r'item/notes', views.item_notes, name='item_notes'),
```

The error I get from chrome is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/crm/item/profile/45/%7B%%20url%20item_notes%20%%7D 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `{% url 'item_notes' %}`. Note the quotes surrounding `item_notes`.

Comment: Yes I did try this. It gave me this error:
    GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/crm/item/profile/45/%7B%%20url%20'item_notes'%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)
    send @ jquery.js:9175
    ajax @ jquery.js:8656
    (anonymous) @ candidate_details.js:15
    dispatch @ jquery.js:4737
    elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4549

Comment: Maybe you are missing a forward slash inside `url(r'item/notes/', ...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Django template tags in your external JS file - Django does not parse that file, which is why you can see the literal tag being appended to your Ajax URL.

You will need to set that value as a global JS var inside an inline script in your template itself.

Comment: thank you, didn't know that. Which value do I need to set as a gobal JS var? The "r'item/notes"?

Comment: You can just use the template tag url, just in your index.html:
`<script> var url = '{%url 'item_notes' %}';</script>` and than use the variable `url` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use an absolute URL to see, if it's the URL that causes the error:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "item/notes",
    success: function(data){
      $('#notesColumn').html('data');
    }
  })
```

Second, why do you GET the notes URL? Aren't you using 'item_profile' for that? In that case, try to GET that URL:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "item/profile/" + "{{ object.pk }}",
    success: function(data){
      $('#notesColumn').html('data');
    }
  })
```

Third, check you JS code, you are missing a closing bracket on `$("#notesTab form").submit`.

Fourth, try to escape the URL. I am not sure which method to use in JS, but I had that problem multiple times where it broke because of unescaped code.

These are just some tips of the top of my head. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Özer! including the {{ object.pk }} does not work since django does not seem to include these template tags.